# Will 14.04 be able to run on an Intel I5 Haswell Processor (Nvidia 750ti, and 8gb of ram)?

Tags: 14.04, intel, system-requirements

- Asrock Fatal1ty z97x killer -
- Intel Core i5 4690k -
- nvidia 750ti -
- Adata 8GB 1600Mhz -

I have read online, there are people who have problem with some Haswell processors, Nvidia video cards, and I cant find any information whether or not does Ubuntu support it.

And thanks in advance for those who help me.

Comment: Booting from the live version of Ubuntu, and choosing the "Try Ubuntu" option during startup is usually the best way to find out if Ubuntu will work on your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pre-built systems Ubuntu has a [Certification Program](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/). For custom-built systems, there really isn't a foolproof way to check other than installing it and seeing if it works. That being said, Ubuntu works out of the box with no extra work required on probably 80% of systems I've installed it on.

For best performance in applications requiring 3D hardware acceleration (i.e. gaming) using nVidia cards it is a good idea to install the official closed-source nVidia drivers as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia). The default in Ubuntu are the open source nouveau drivers, which while perfectly fine for general work, only provide 2D acceleration and thus are not adequate for recent computer games.

If you have a card with nVidia Optimus (aka Hybrid Graphics), this can lead to some problems, but most people find [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) to be a good solution.

If you encounter any problems while using "Try Ubuntu" from Live Media or after installation, come back and search for/ask another question. Welcome to Ubuntu!

Comment: I think ill latter give it a go and installing Ubuntu then i will see what is not compatible. And maybe do you know if Ubuntu 14.04 has support for 3d modeling programs like - Maya 3d, 3ds Max -and AAA title games like Crysis3?

Comment: You'd have to check each application individually. Unfortunately application support is probably the main disadvantage for Linux at the moment, but is slowly improving. Maya 3d says it supports Linux, but 3d max does not, according to their system requirements pages on autodesk. You might still be able to get them to work using `wine` or `playonlinux` though. The best source for linux games is currently `steam`, which is actively working to increase support for games on linux. According to google crisis will run on Ubuntu using `playonlinux`.

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your help. ill try to see if my applications are compactible or not . but in the mean time im going to google around see if theres anything that i might need . once again thank you, hope you can help me later when ill be in need of one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to use a usb-stick (or cd) to test ubuntu out. then you can look if everything runs. hope this works.
just get ubuntu on usb or cd and boot from there. then you have the option to try ubuntu without installing anything.
(pretty new with ubuntu too).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i forgot to mention that i am also building my new computer this year (Sorry for that mistake). and my computer is not yet finished building( i will finish it 2 weeks later) so that's why i wanted to know . Would there be any other way to check it?